# Interactive mode within "with" statements

Tags: python, handle, contextmanager

[With statement context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) are convenient for many purposes. However, they can be inconvenient in an interactive shell, because the entire `with` statement is executed as a whole block, e.g.:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin:
    print(fin.readline())  # The result does not immediately output to the console
    for i in range(10):  # I may want to choose the number depending on the previous line's output
                         # (or do something else entirely), but I cannot
        print(fin.readline())  # Or any other sort of processing
```

As shown, this may be a problem if, for example, I want to "explore" a file's content before deciding what to do with it. What I usually end up doing is either reading the entire file into a string before processing it, or use multiple `with` statements to open the file multiple times, but obviously both of those solutions have limitations (e.g. the file may be too large to read into the memory, or the context manager in question may not be a file at all).

A more general solution would be to eschew the `with` statement and use `fin.close()` instead. However, some context manager classes I use may not provide a `close()` method in their public interface. Of course I could explicitly write `mycontextmanager.__exit__(None, None, None)`, but that seems awkward. Also, it is also entirely possible that I'd forget to close the context manager, which is not a big deal for files, but may be more problematic for e.g. an internet session.

I could also use [finalizers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#comparing-finalizers-with-del-methods) to make sure that things are closed, but relying on the garbage collector for anything other than memory leaks seems a shaky way to do things, so I feel that finalizers should be a supplemental solution at best.

So is there a more elegant solution to the problem of using context managers in an interactive shell? Should my own context manager classes always provide something like a `close()` method as a good practice?

Comment: Not a bad question. I think you will have to call `__enter__` and `__exit__` manually. Personally, I rarely bother to be tidy in interactive sessions. Those are for goofing around.

Comment: You first solution of reading the whole file to a string seems to be the best option for  REPL sessions. First, your file would have to be *very* large to saturate the memory, second REPL sessions are meant to quick test, if your code is more involved you should use a standard Python script (use logging to dump transient state).

Comment: Not that this behavior is common to very Python block, in a REPL interpreter you first have to close the block for the code to be executed. For instance your second print statement inside the for-loop is only executed when the block is closed, not when the print statement is written.

Comment: @LouisLac That's a good point. Of course, when I need to do something similar for a for-loop, I would just manually set `i = 0` and run individual statements, essentially "unfolding" the loop. I guess explicitly calling `__enter__` and `__exit__` is how one "unfold" a with-statement.

Comment: Maybe [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) would be useful here? I've never used it myself, just found it from a quick Google.

Answer (score 1):

Run an interactive session through the debugger.

Run the code as a script but put a `breakpoint()` in a point of interest.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) for the debugger docs.

- `s` to step
- `n` (next) to step over functions
- `c` (continue) to resume execution
- `p <name>` to display names's value
- `! <statement>` to execute a statement
- `display <name>` is useful too.

Comment: This is too "heavyweight" for the use case I described in my question: Most of the time I'm just exploring and may not want to write a script at all. However I upvoted because I think this is good advice if someone has some script to debug.